# Missing a throwing roll in savage worlds with an 'area of effect' weapon

Tags: savage-worlds

In Savage Worlds the rules for Area Of Effect say that if you miss your throwing or shooting roll, the **blast** deviates, and they reinforce this by saying you move the blast template.

I added emphasis because the way I interpret this, the line of sight does not change and so you can actually end up throwing a grenade around a corner on a botched throw.

Now this makes a bit of sense for a grenade, but how about a Bazooka?

I guess what I am really asking is if after you figure out how far and in which direction a **blast** deviates, do you then check to see if there was anything in the way between the target and the person who made the attack?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Savage Worlds* does not have any special rules to deal with a blast deviating into a location that the attacker cannot see. In order to keep the game going, it's assumed that it got there *somehow* and there are no rules to try to correct for this.

Possible explanations for how it got to a location out of line of sight include:

- The grenade bounced off the ground, a wall, or other barrier
- There was an arc to the bazooka shot, or the canister was thrown with a curveball
- Wind pushed the projectile in that direction
- The shot went over, under, or through the obstacle
- User error made the projectile go wildly
- Divine intervention made it go there

If none of those make sense, the GM can always just rule that it hit whatever is blocking line of sight and therefore the blast explodes on the near side of the obstacle.

Comment: Or, last option, the GM rules on the spot that it does indeed hit an intervening obstacle.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Good call, I've added it

Comment: Yeah that was our instinct and the way we have been handling it. It just seems so odd at long ranges in tight quarters.